# Dynamics CRM 2011, Call multiple entities in one go

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on application which all the master data from CRM entities seperately using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk (CRM web service).

Issue is, currently we are calling all entities seperately, which makes WCF call earch time.

I am trying to implement solution, in which I will call seperate entities in one go, so that in 1 WCF call I have all the master data.

So Sql Equivalent will be
Select x from Entity1; Select y from Entity2

I am using QueryExpression & then calling RetrieveMultiple(query) method.

Link mentioned below does not have implementation for Select. Is there code sample available for this?

Any help will be appreatiated.

Thanks,
Div

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ExecuteMultiple message. Following article describes sample of usage - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863604.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response, I gone through refrence you given. I guess it has sample for Create/Update/ Delete but not for select from multiple entities. Can you provide some refrence where I can find multiple selects.